# Pivoting rows into a Query

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Hi wondering if what I am doing is even possible and if so if anyone can help?

I have a query with several columns and on another table there is a column with several different reasons why there was an exclusion.
What I want to do is pivot from that column so beside my orginal query have the 3 exclusion reasons pivoted out and then display an X in whichever pivoted column is the reason for that exclusion.

1)
Source Data is from two tables in SQL server

2)Expected Result

```
Broker Date       Excluded No_Activity No_Money No_Credit
123    11/11/16   Yes            x  
124    11/11/16   Yes                      x
125    11/11/16   Yes                                x
```

3) What I tried

```
select distinct pt.brk_id as 'Broker',
pt.dte as 'Date',
pt.exclud as 'Excluded'
from broker_t pt
left join exclusion_t et
on et.dte = pt.dte

select 
'x' as 'No_Activity',
'x' as 'No_Money',
'x' as 'No_Credit'
from (select excl_dcs
from exclusion_t) t

pivot
(
max(excl_dcs)
for excl_dcs in
("No_Activity",
"No_Money",
"No_Credit"
) piv
```

4) Current Output

```
  Broker Date       Excluded 
    123    11/11/16   Yes            
    124    11/11/16   Yes           
    125    11/11/16   Yes     

No_Activity No_Money No_Credit
      x        x        x
```

Comment: Im not sure about your data, Try to be more specific in your question. Say something like 1) this is my source data 2) this is my expected result 3) this is what I try 4) this is my current output

Comment: dont post in comment, just edit your question to make it clear

Comment: Edited now if that's still not any clearer let me know a bit of a newcomer to SQL not great at speaking the language yet,

Comment: what happen with the source data? Only magicians hide the source before show result ;) We need source data to understand how get your desire result